# Unexpected output when printing time.Time

Tags: go, time

"I'm trying to output the values of a channel , which received values from a struct, which should be a string and time. It outputs those two, but then it includes this strange line " +0300 +03 m=+0.001997101" after the time."

Tried many other things from fmt package, but still no help. Tried things from the time package too

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

type widget struct {
    Label string
    Time  time.Time
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan widget)
    sc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)

    signal.Notify(sc, syscall.SIGINT,
            syscall.SIGTERM,
        syscall.SIGHUP,
        syscall.SIGKILL,
        syscall.SIGSEGV,
    )

    go func() {
            sig := <-sc
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println(sig)
        done <- true
    }()

    go send(c)
    go receive(c)
    <-done
    fmt.Println("Program exited")

}

func send(p chan<- widget) {
    producer := widget{
            "widget_id_34",
        time.Now(),
    }
    p <- producer
}
//where im grtting the problem from i beilieve
func receive(c <-chan widget) {
    out := <-c
    fmt.Printf("%v", out)
    //fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, <-c)
}
```

Comment: [widget_1 20:27:38.482204] my answer is supposed to look like this,  and im not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: "Tried many other things from fmt package," For time, the obvious place to look is the documentation for [package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time)..

Answer (score 0):

The `m` field is the [monotonic time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks). Per the docs:

> The canonical way to strip a monotonic clock reading is to use `t = t.Round(0)`.

Doing so yields a time without a `m` value. The `+0300` is the time zone offset, which is part of the time value (without it, the time value would be useless, because it would have a margin of error of +/- 23 hours).